# Regular expressions in ReplaceAll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I need a regular expression that can search a particular substring not enclosed within single or double quotes.
Example if i need to search "query" in the text below

**This is a very good query,
but we need don't need this "bad query in quotes" neither do this ' single query quotes'.
What i need is perfect queryexpression that can resolve my issue.**

Then i should get desired result as-> **query** i.e before good word and **queryexpression**

Comment: do you need regex for getting "This is a very good" as output? Be more specific.

Comment: I just need to extract query keyword from the text in bold not contained within quotes. Here query keyword could be either substring or complete string too.And yes i need only Regex for it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And how do you define "between quotes", do they need to be balanced? If so, Regex isn't going to work in all cases.

Comment: i have tried something like this (?<!")(?<!')query(?!")(?!') it works when it is complete string within quotes but fails when it is a substring contained in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very hard to solve with Regular Expressions. It may seem simple and you may choose a regex like the one you've created so far, taking in account the fact that there may be other text before the quote (if variable width look-arounds are supported by your regex engine):

```
 (?<!"[^"])query(?![^"]*")|(?<!'[^'])query(?![^']*')
```

But it will fail for a text like:

> This is a "quoted piece of text**" that proceeds a *Query* especially when one follows it "**as well"

Since the Look behind will detect the closing quote of the quoted piece of text as part of a possible quote of the word Query.

Similar issues will occur when the word Query is between two pieces of abbreviated text:

> It**'s hard to know when a *Query* doesn'**t return any values when you don't know the data.

If you were using C# you could have made use of the concept of balancing groups, but since you're not and Javascript doesn't support that construct, you have ended up in a situation where it's going to be very hard to satisfy your search criteria without using a more advanced technique than Regular Expressions.

With a lot of tweaking you may be able to detect most cases, but a foolproof solution is going to be neigh impossible. Especially when limited to the regex features supported by Javascript. regex engines with variable length look-arounds and support for balancing groups or recursion allow you to get closer, see [this article for an example of matching opening and closing quotes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21183/In-Depth-with-NET-RegEx-Balanced-Grouping).

```
@"
(?>
    "\b (?<DEPTH> )
    |
    \b" (?<-DEPTH> )
    |
    [^"]*
)*
(?(DEPTH)(?!))
"
```

Though that would still fail for other funny cases like

> There are situations where the double quote character (**") is used in the wrong location in a *query*, for example: 'select test from "**table'

Comment: It is failing for very case have you tested this solution

Comment: I know. That's what I said. And those cases cannot be solved using Regex in javascript.

Comment: So how this could be achieved using C#?

Comment: then please provide me that solution i can use it even through .Net

Comment: You'll have to better define your inputs and output. There are too many corner cases for us to just "give you a regex".